# GEE Feature Collections and Dates

Tags: date, google-fusion-tables, google-earth-engine

I have a fusiontable based feature collection in Google-Earth-Engine that includes a date column. I would like to cast the FC into an empty image and display with graduated colours for increasing dates - so that when the Inspector is used a human readable date is displayed.

```
var empty64 = ee.Image().toInt64();
var outlines = empty64.paint({
  featureCollection: SomeFeatureCollection,
  color: 'StartDate',
});
```

If I add this to the map as a layer I get the date as a 13-digit format that I can't read. How can I change this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Per the API reference for [Image.paint](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#eeimagepaint), `color` must be an object name or a number. To me, that means the EE API will interpret the object as a number, meaning a `Date` object will be converted from a string to a numerical representation. In this case, that's the "milliseconds since epoch" format.

Without a way to add metadata to a FeatureCollection (i.e. so you could store the associated datestring along with the other parameters of the feature), I don't think you can show a human readable date in the inspector.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I thought. Seems there is no option to store date as there is no option to draw the image in a "date format" for pixels!